# Resizing datagrid content and controls according to device screen size in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I am working on an application which should be able to **resize** itself according to the **device screen size**. I managed to do this with altMobileResizer.

But I am **not** able to resize the content of the **data grid row template**.

Is there a way that I can resize the data grid content?

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dgColumnWidth property. Like:

```
set the dgColumnWidth["column1"] of group "myDataGrid" to tWidth
```

There are other properties you may need and you can set most of them via the dgProp property. Like:

```
set the dgProp["Row Height"] of group "myDataGrid" to 75
set the dgProp["text Size"] of group "myDataGrid" to 22
set the dgProp["header text Size"] of group "myDataGrid" to 22
set the dgProp["header height"] of group "myDataGrid" to 35
```

Have a look at the datagrid properties at http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/datagrid/l/7343-data-grid-properties

Comment: By this i can resize the datagrid but how can i resize the inner content of row template(like button ,images,lables)?

Comment: If you want total control of the datagrid layout I suggest that you switch to a "form" layout instead. There is nothing preventing that you layout your "form" as a "table". The datagrid uses a row template to display the data. You can get that via dgProp["row template"]. I guess you can get to your buttons etc via that but I haven't tested it myself.